# Mysql Get data for Last Six weeks using JOIN

Tags: mysql, sql, join

I have edited the query by selecting all the Employees data which have done assessments in past six weeks. Logically it should each employee two time if it has done assessments in two weeks but this query shows single record.

```
 select 
   AssessmentEmployee.
   EmployeeName,
   AVG(AssessmentListing.AssessmentScore),
   DATE_FORMAT((STR_TO_DATE(`AssessmentSubmittedDatetime`, '%d-%b-%Y %I:%i %p')) , '%Y-%m-%v') as _month 
 from AssessmentEmployee 
 LEFT JOIN AssessmentListing 
 ON  AssessmentEmployee.AssessmentID=AssessmentListing.AssessmentID 
 WHERE (STR_TO_DATE(`AssessmentSubmittedDatetime`, '%d-%b-%Y %I:%i %p') >= DATE_FORMAT(NOW() - INTERVAL 6 Week, '%Y' )) 
 group by AssessmentEmployee.EmployeeName
```

I  have following table which I am using.

```
AssessmentEmployee
 ID
 AssessmentID
 EmployeeName
```

Other table is AssessmentListing

```
ID
AssessmentID
AssessmentSubmittedDateTime
AssessmentScore
```

I want to get the employees who have score/ done assessments in Last sex weeks and their average score.

Sample of Data Column of AssessmentListing

```
ID  AssessmentID     AssessmentSubmittedDatetime     AssessmentScore 
1     040416024720     04-Apr-2016 02:48 PM             50
```

Comment: You need to group by `week number` and `employee name` together.

Comment: When you say `group by AssessmentEmployee.EmployeeName` that is asking for all of the data for each value of `EmployeeName` to be summarised into a single row. So of course you will only get one row for each (not the two you were expecting).

Comment: @Turophile I want that lets say Adam and Jackon have done in past two weeks So it should show for both and also if any week in past six week does not have record than it takes previous weeks it should not take other weeks

Comment: @1000111 I have added bot together but it should not show only last six weeks but lets say last six weeks are 22,21,20,19,18,17 so lets say if does not have data for 21 then it also picks 16 it should show only last six if not available not to show

Comment: what's the data type of `AssessmentSubmittedDateTime`?

Comment: @1000111 Its VARCAHAR

Comment: Would you please show some sample data of that column? Need to know in which format the date times are stored.

Comment: @1000111 I have added sample data please have a look thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please try the following query:

```
select 
   AssessmentEmployee.
   EmployeeName,
   AVG(AssessmentListing.AssessmentScore),
   DATE_FORMAT((STR_TO_DATE(`AssessmentSubmittedDatetime`, '%d-%b-%Y %I:%i %p')) , '%Y-%v') as year_week
 from AssessmentEmployee 
 LEFT JOIN AssessmentListing 
 ON  AssessmentEmployee.AssessmentID=AssessmentListing.AssessmentID 
 WHERE UNIX_TIMESTAMP(DATE_FORMAT(STR_TO_DATE(`AssessmentSubmittedDatetime`,'%d-%b-%Y %I:%i %p'),'%Y-%m-%d')) >= UNIX_TIMESTAMP(CURDATE() - INTERVAL 6 WEEK)
 group by AssessmentEmployee.EmployeeName, year_week;
```

You shouldn't store date / time as string. Otherwise embrace these cumbersome jobs while processing them.

Comment: you are right but I did not thought we will be getting for report like this thats why used

Comment: So tell me now did that work? are you getting expected output? @DilshadAli

Comment: I am getting out put but let me confirm

Comment: can we start on chat if possible later

Comment: sure. Go for it please.

Comment: Join in this [**chat room**](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/113589/dilshad-ali-and-1000111)

Answer (score 0):

you're doing an average so it will average the 2 scores if they take it twice.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT *, SUM(AssessmentScore) as total, SUM(AssessmentScore)/6 as avg
FROM `assessmentlisting` 
WHERE STR_TO_DATE(`AssessmentSubmittedDatetime`, '%d-%b-%Y %I:%i %p') > DATE_FORMAT(NOW() - INTERVAL 6 Week, '%Y-%m-%d %I:%i %p' ) 
GROUP BY assessmentlisting.AssessmentID
```

Hope it will works.